# How to bind Array properties with ng-tags-input autocomplete

Tags: ng-tags-input, angularjs-1.5

I have the following code for generating the tags in ng-tags-input

```
$scope.loadTags = function () {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(vm.campusesList);
   })
}
```

Inside the **vm.campusesList** array I have multiple objects containing multiple properties. What I want is to take the **name** property from each object and use that in autocomplete tag.

Here is my view.

```
<tags-input ng-model="vm.campusesList">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags()"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the property name you want the text in autocomplete fashion.I have written code for you below. **display-property="name"** inside  plays the role in search where as  **key-property="name"**   will accept the repeated name in your list if any. For further clarity or help post your JSON Response. Enjoy!!

```
<tags-input name="campusesListAutocomplete"
    ng-model="vm.campusesList"
    display-property="name"
    key-property="name"  
    highlight-matched-text="true">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"/>
</tags-input>
```